# Return the values ​of two scales in a tooltip (echarts barometer)

Tags: javascript, echarts

I tried to create a tooltip (echarts) that returns the values ​​associated with the two series present in a barometer. The first series has values ​​from 0 to 100 and the second from 0 to 60. The problem is that it is only considering the values ​​from 0 to 100, but not from 0 to 60.

This is my code:

```js
const mychartspider1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugespiderinc1'));

function updateGaugeSpider1(value1, value2) {
  const option = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item',
      formatter: function(params) {
        if (params.seriesIndex === 0) {
          return params.seriesName + '<br>' + params.value.toFixed(2) + '%';
        } else if (params.seriesIndex === 1) {
          return params.seriesName + '<br>' + value2.toFixed(0);
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'gauge',
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        splitNumber: 10,
        radius: '80%',
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: [
              [1, '#008cba']
            ],
            width: 3
          }
        },
        splitLine: {
          distance: -18,
          length: 18,
          lineStyle: {
            color: '#008cba'
          }
        },
        axisTick: {
          distance: -12,
          length: 10,
          lineStyle: {
            color: '#008cba'
          }
        },
        axisLabel: {
          distance: -40,
          color: '#008cba',
          fontSize: 20,
          fontFamily: 'Lato' // Adicionado fontFamily
        },
        anchor: {
          show: true,
          size: 20,
          itemStyle: {
            borderColor: '#000',
            borderWidth: 2
          }
        },
        pointer: {
          offsetCenter: [0, '10%'],
          icon: 'path://M2090.36389,615.30999 L2090.36389,615.30999 C2091.48372,615.30999 2092.40383,616.194028 2092.44859,617.312956 L2096.90698,728.755929 C2097.05155,732.369577 2094.2393,735.416212 2090.62566,735.56078 C2090.53845,735.564269 2090.45117,735.566014 2090.36389,735.566014 L2090.36389,735.566014 C2086.74736,735.566014 2083.81557,732.63423 2083.81557,729.017692 C2083.81557,728.930412 2083.81732,728.84314 2083.82081,728.755929 L2088.2792,617.312956 C2088.32396,616.194028 2089.24407,615.30999 2090.36389,615.30999 Z',
          length: '115%'
        },
        detail: {
          valueAnimation: true,
          precision: 1,
          formatter: '{value}%',
          padding: [2, 1, 5, 2],
          borderRadius: 5,
          color: '#333333',
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          backgroundColor: '#92a192'
        },
        title: {
          offsetCenter: [0, '-50%'],
          fontFamily: 'Lato'
        },
        data: [{
            value: value1,
            name: 'PRESSURE1',
            title: {
              color: 'orange',
              offsetCenter: ['0%', '-50%'],
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontWeight: 'bolder'
            },
            detail: {
              offsetCenter: ['-40%', '110%'],
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              borderWidth: 3,
              borderColor: 'orange'
            },
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'orange',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#858383'
            }
          },
          {
            value: value2,
            name: 'PRESSURE2',
            title: {
              color: 'green',
              offsetCenter: ['0%', '-30%'],
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontWeight: 'bolder'
            },
            detail: {
              offsetCenter: ['40%', '110%'],
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              borderWidth: 3,
              borderColor: 'green',
              color: '#333333'
            },
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'green',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#858383'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'gauge',
        min: 0,
        max: 60,
        splitNumber: 6,
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: [
              [1, '#858383']
            ],
            width: 3
          }
        },
        splitLine: {
          distance: -2,
          length: 18,
          lineStyle: {
            color: '#858383'
          }
        },
        axisTick: {
          distance: 0,
          length: 10,
          lineStyle: {
            color: '#858383'
          }
        },
        axisLabel: {
          distance: 10,
          fontSize: 25,
          color: '#858383'
        },
        pointer: {
          show: false
        },
        title: {
          show: false
        },
        anchor: {
          show: true,
          size: 14,
          itemStyle: {
            color: 'red'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  mychartspider1.setOption(option);
}

function updategaugespider1() {
  $('#sliderspidervalue1').text($('#number1').val());
  $('#sliderspidervalue2').text($('#number2').val());
}

updategaugespider1();
updateGaugeSpider1(Number($('#number1').val()), Number($('#number2').val()));

$('#number1').on('input', function() {
  updategaugespider1();
  updateGaugeSpider1(Number($(this).val()), Number($('#number2').val()));
});

$('#number2').on('input', function() {
  updategaugespider1();
  updateGaugeSpider1(Number($('#number1').val()), Number($(this).val()));
});

/// event click
mychartspider1.on('click', {
  dataIndex: 0
}, function(params) {
  alert('clicked')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="gaugespiderinc1" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<input type="range" id="number1" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50">
<input type="range" id="number2" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="75">
```

See that it only returns the values ​​in the series from 0 to 100, but I need both to be returned (0 to 100 and 0 to 60) for each of the pointers.

Expected outcome:

[image]

In other words, I need to consider this scale (from 0 to 60) as well. Thus, the values ​​in the tooltip for the first pointer would be **50** and **30**, as in the image. For the second pointer, the values ​​in the tooltip should be **75** and **45**.

```
                {
                  type: 'gauge',
                  min: 0,
                  max: 60,
                  splitNumber: 6,
                  axisLine: {
                    lineStyle: {
                      color: [[1, '#858383']],
                      width: 3
                    }
                  },
                  splitLine: {
                    distance: -2,
                    length: 18,
                    lineStyle: {
                      color: '#858383'
                    }
                  },
                  axisTick: {
                    distance: 0,
                    length: 10,
                    lineStyle: {
                      color: '#858383'
                    }
                  },
                  axisLabel: {
                    distance: 10,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: '#858383'
                  },
                  pointer: {
                    show: true
                  },
                  title: {
                    show: false
                  },
                  anchor: {
                    show: true,
                    size: 14,
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: 'red'
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Your code looks like it's working absolutely fine in the snippet I created in your question. Please be much more speficic about what the problem is, and what the expected behaviour should be.

Comment: Also, as an aside to the question, DO NOT define 2 functions with the same name only differentiated by their casing. That's asking for multiple headaches. Name your functions properly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan See that there are two meters, one from 0 to 100 and the other from 0 to 60. I would like the tooltip for each of the pointers to return the values ​​associated with these two series, but it is only returning one series, the one from 0 to 100. It must also return from 0 to 60. See this when hovering the mouse over each of the pointers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In the case of the first pointer, it is returning 50%, but it would also have to return 30 (which is an integer associated with the second series) in the tooltip. Hover your mouse over the pointer and see that only the 50% value appears.

Comment: please note,  `params.seriesIndex` is always 0 no matter which pointer you hover

Comment: Just compute both values whenever the callback function is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=DYUwLgBAbghsCuICMEC8ECsAGA3AWAChRJYEQAmNCAdg3wMIHsAHMAS0YDsqBvQiARDCNGwdswBcEPgUGCwAJzYBzZSAVSA5GzAgAtpoA0_ORABmjBXphhdG8_E4BjdlwAUzGAph6AzgEppE1MIBXB4BW4AWRsACwA6BUZHABM3N1JEFAB6CAA2LECAKggkLEKIAGoIACIIAFIIAB4AIwUAPjrqzIoq2oaa-hCAX2CIYeNZQV91NhBfKQBtGRCBMABPZhAtZRh4NSMxuT02TiksSdWIawAPKTKLo-nmYB0AOXg9FvV7x6mQ7wpNjwBYQTQADiw9UO_1MMBubF8ABlTtsgrCQq9OCAAMobUBSFZXQROUSWJZPK6LJCGMEAYnK4KcLRgmgAupTTGzLsSBAB3NgpMCxKQAZk5AlGGMEE05vheOhR2MJEogQN8YBgzjRAFokOCeVdQJxlML7gbVVjcfi0UTeaTgOT6YzmazVVKrrLpQJ4YiACpsJwAaxV3sE6s12qkevIhtWxtNItKf15Vrx6wJ6N5AgdTs0DKwTJZmndnK9V19yJg32Aod5Ea1Tl1ABYU8Tc_Z8y7i3GQhZOGAcWwAF5o8htq79sAAMR8bGA6y0SJsjE0EGyuQAgkCnBxODAUoxzFwZ3OF2Xe4JG7EnXbVr4b3ypIpEJe5L4R2OJ6sdPp05m7yuFpLBSdQAGEyU7AssBhbMIGAhRQIUAB1QUzQgchSzDctVmYRhTjsOtiUYMwzBmMAwJAAcfggRYLjBMpoW5VVAy4LRPDNDconHABOLB4lFPJRXBHjDDyJAMAErAeJkiAkV4_jBOE0TxMk0VpNksDeKQeJm3BUVqFjVSpJkniMOk8hdKwYTRTEpA8niJAeNbchwXMnjLObPSMBUpBqAEpByB4jA8jk3iHL4vIeINQzwXiWgfKCiAtOk_ysAwCSMEMahRUswTguoah3ObeJyFFHjbJyyTm3s8hAvc_i8nIEK8my0VJJCrBqDclK-PiDBhObLKqv6vJm3IKKGt0jK_Lajq8gKJBmympSRLm0bFuW-TpMUoS1pGlqsCW5Lx3BBzqGbHLWoOhajuW07RXicFMuoNrLKE8bRXM_Snpe7KgviI7qCiygUp-56MAwV7YviCqsBqygHt-nLYxh8Fm1FY6kfBU6aRhhKPLM7bwTi8hqA8uz_MxoKQpOws4ty8rWvEhynJctzTp40qvK6uy1I0syFIEvbfP50yIAALVg4kE3QzQkAk6EL05UDNXnIirh6TdODYaxXDOIQFFfVVmDCXcPzY0o30ECwrBsQiwR4Hphmha2BE8FIgRNJZYytzBaXIZiwwEBCkIAJQPYFQSy1UOy0OlRUTpPpcnE9ZxOBclxXFPVhZYNlCSVIIMdKCPJgJzyBLbDrfYMAANVEiyPASjqPsOjaU0HVsCYt3jwHdP50XMFl2EKvPWtlIbBgJZANWHopB6GlVQEfc9DRTQAAUw4AURxHEAFUd6QHOrlr-vg9MOOwUsLUDl7uRG_IluHcWTQoSMMEu_foO4IEKcB8zsPbO98bYnmQiAFQsQwBaGAsAJCY9sw4XrOAGA6ssy_0fs3KiL9O6tldgxRi7IQF_zTmeIemgR6rmIfBEC6hUJCiTLZZeghQ7gUgloG-JoQAIN5Eg4kv49D_ltMwnM7Dr7eC4SfYkrCUJoSTEvC-cgZHFzzHScEGB9L6R4cSD0Oje6zxCPPaAcBECxmYavdeW9d4Hx3pXEBZ9hGKJJGIzQBcQBUSkVcTBFFsE0Vfu_DuOp1I9xEX3U8GdyGUM8asKc4DIHQLBLA-BzC-FXFVqg2s6C4LeOfn4zQeCP7y0IT_X-_8yFZ1HtQmR9D0JMKcSHWhCgVGdjcR46hV98xJ2TikkBAihEa2zB01pnBokhGqXI-4VTGnNPjuozRoptGeiwlcDk0pUlZNMBsLYOw9h305CcA235jjwikAUa28pXhgA-F8GirVOSViVI41MqJ-kbKuFfRYoTqQdzURomy7JmElN5AKBhYplmrHWQIC5ipUQDJCA2KMEAdRmIvrLeRFpUUvJtHC1YHTfnzMWaYXRIxraVgDMGHFcgEVNnOL3NFvw6VYozE8wZLj8X_PBSS-5CIqw1kpeGREkYaXJl7lOIco4pDNV7niuZHLq6cjwgRGiBjpiPikGYOAMxlZhgcfyqFarzCapANqiszgbz2BVfqxgT5DbGwvh-CVpRmy9z6dit5uKXFhBSISuQxKiVPD9asyUOAgA) is an example that should work:

```js
formatter: function(params) {
   return Math.round((value1 / 60) * 100) + " % <br>" + value2 + " %";
}
```

Comment: But the value of the value2 tip needs to be 30, as shown in the image. Tooltip values ​​must indicate the new value each time the pointers are modified. This doesn't happen.

Comment: I am just showcasing how to resolve your issue using the formatter function. You just need to pass the correct values.